# Problems with aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Im trying to learn how to make sql like queries in Mongo and found this aggregation framework, when i run the code the average always turns out "0" all though the 'columns' have numbers in them, if i understand it right mongoDB saves all values as a strings( the number where integers at first in my sql server database which i transferred to mongoDB) so i dont have to care about types really when working with MongoDB? Can someone see why my average function dont work? The ordered quantity has number between 1.000000 - 7.000000.

```
DBCollection order = db.getCollection("Orderstatus");


DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("Company", "100") );


DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("Facility", 1);
fields.put("Ordered quantity", 1);
fields.put("_id", 0);
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );

DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$Facility");
groupFields.put("average", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$Ordered quantity"));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);


AggregationOutput output = order.aggregate( match, project,group );
System.out.println(output);
```

The thing is that i thought that the numbers would be as integers since i got them from my sql server database where they are stored as integers using the code below. I see now that i use getString() when getting the values, is that why the numbers are strings in mongodb? how can i get them as integers?? i really want to be able to manipulate them as numbers!

```
StringBuilder orderstatus = new StringBuilder();
orderstatus.append("SELECT * FROM dbo.fact_orderstatus");
PreparedStatement t = connect.prepareStatement(orderstatus.toString());  
DBCollection orderstat = db.getCollection("Orderstatus");
ResultSet v = t.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsm = t.getMetaData();
int column = rsm.getColumnCount();

while (v.next()) {
BasicDBObject orderObj = new BasicDBObject();
for(int x=1; x<column +1; x++){
String namn= rsm.getColumnName(x);

String custNum = (v.getString(x));
if (custNum != null && !custNum.trim().isEmpty()
&& custNum.length() != 0)
orderObj.append(namn, custNum);

}


orderstat.insert(orderObj)
```

Comment: your understanding of types is incorrect - if you store numbers as string you won't be able to manipulate them as numbers, including averaging them out.  Make sure you store your numbers as numbers (no quotes!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that MongoDB *does* care about types of values you save.

If you want to store numbers, make sure they are not quoted otherwise they become stored as strings and you lose ability to manipulate them as numbers.

Javascript also differentiates between numbers and string, but MongoDB supports more number types than simple JavaScript.  You can read more [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/).

Comment: You can use getInt instead of getString() to preserve type.

Comment: Thanks Asya! I added some code that shows how i get the data from the source database, i only need to do getInt on the integers and getString on the strings, i tried to put an if statement and parseInt to only use getInt if the value is an integer but i just cant figure it out! Do you know an easy way to make sure that all the data types get in to mongoDB correctly?

Comment: I suggest you open a separate Java question since getting data from mySQL isn't related to MongoDB so it shouldn't be in this question's discussion